# How to remove j: from a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie with j: prefixed, how do i remove it and access the original object

j:{"p":"5c2f09f9ba729f26ccd9e57b","h":"5c2d6ba83a84360390600f7b"}

how do i access p an h

Answer (score 0):

if it's simple string you need use simple JSON.parse;

```js
const res = JSON.parse('j:{"p":"5c2f09f9ba729f26ccd9e57b","h":"5c2d6ba83a84360390600f7b"}'.slice(2));

console.log(res);
```

But if this a php serializer object, you can parse this only with special libraries, for example:

```
npm php-serialize
```

Comment: but you can't hard-code that string as an agument to JSON.parse()

Comment: i add snippet, why not?

Comment: regexp it;s not good solution, you need figure which format used